# Find length of same pattern in vector

Tags: r, function

I have a vector like this

```
t<-c(9,9,9,9,9,9,10,10,10,10,8,8,8,8,8,200,8,8,7,9,9,9,9,9)
```

What I would like to get is the indexes of each start and end of each run of the same characters. Take 9. The output would be 1 to 6 and 20 to 24. For 7 it would be only 19. Is there a way to write a function in which to input the specific number (like 9 or 7) and which will then just output the indexes as outlined above in R?

Comment: Check out function `?rle`

Answer (score 1):

Following simple, adjustable code using basic programming methods & base R may be helpful:

```
t<-c(9,9,9,9,9,9,10,10,10,10,8,8,8,8,8,200,8,8,7,9,9,9,9,9)
i = 1; j=1
while(!is.na(t[i+2])){
    while(t[i]==t[i+1]) {i=i+1; if(is.na(t[i+1]))break; }
    i=i+1
    cat("number=",t[i-1],"times=",(i-j),"start=",j,"end=",i-1,'\n')
    j = i
}

number= 9 times= 6 start= 1 end= 6 
number= 10 times= 4 start= 7 end= 10 
number= 8 times= 5 start= 11 end= 15 
number= 200 times= 1 start= 16 end= 16 
number= 8 times= 2 start= 17 end= 18 
number= 7 times= 1 start= 19 end= 19 
number= 9 times= 5 start= 20 end= 24
```

To get a data frame:

```
outdf = data.frame(number=numeric(), start=numeric(), end=numeric(), times=numeric())
i = 1; j=1
while(!is.na(t[i+2])){
    while(t[i]==t[i+1]) {i=i+1; if(is.na(t[i+1]))break; }
    i=i+1
    outdf[nrow(outdf)+1,] = c(t[i-1], j, i-1, i-j)
    j = i
}
outdf
  number start end times
1      9     1   6     6
2     10     7  10     4
3      8    11  15     5
4    200    16  16     1
5      8    17  18     2
6      7    19  19     1
7      9    20  24     5
```

For a function for one number:

```
myfn = function(num){
    outdf = data.frame(number=numeric(), start=numeric(), end=numeric(), times=numeric())
    i = 1; j=1
    while(!is.na(t[i+2])){
        while(t[i]==t[i+1]) {i=i+1; if(is.na(t[i+1]))break; }
        i=i+1
        if(t[i-1]==num) {outdf[nrow(outdf)+1,] = c(t[i-1], j, i-1, i-j)}
        j = i
    }
    outdf
}

myfn(10)
  number start end times
1     10     7  10     4

myfn(9)
  number start end times
1      9     1   6     6
2      9    20  24     5

myfn(8)
  number start end times
1      8    11  15     5
2      8    17  18     2
```

EDIT: As suggested by beginneR and Carl Witthoft in comments:

```
rle(t)
Run Length Encoding
  lengths: int [1:7] 6 4 5 1 2 1 5
  values : num [1:7] 9 10 8 200 8 7 9
```

But output here is a bit cryptic.

Comment: You're doing a lot of hard work to reproduce 3 lines of code in `rle` :-)

Answer (score 1):

As beginneR  said, just use `rle` .  the output gives you the start point for each change in value, so it's easy to calculate the run locations.

```
 t<-c(9,9,9,9,9,9,10,10,10,10,8,8,8,8,8,200,8,8,7,9,9,9,9,9)
 rlet<-rle(t)
 rlet
Run Length Encoding
  lengths: int [1:7] 6 4 5 1 2 1 5
  values : num [1:7] 9 10 8 200 8 7 9
```

Just sum the `lengths` values up to each instance of `values==9`  and so on.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the `rle` solution

```
f <- function(t, n) {
    x <- rle(t)
    i <- x$values == n
    end.pos <- cumsum(x$lengths)[i]
    start.pos <- end.pos - x$lengths[i] + 1
    data.frame(from = start.pos, to = end.pos)
}

t <- c(9,9,9,9,9,9,10,10,10,10,8,8,8,8,8,200,8,8,7,9,9,9,9,9)
f(t, 9)  
#  from to
#     1  6
#    20 24
f(t, 7)
#  from to
#    19 19
```

You can modify the return value of `f` to get the output in your desired format.

Alternatively, use `which` with `diff`, which gives better performance

```
f2 <- function(t, n) {
    i <- which(t == n)
    start.i <- c(0, which(diff(i) != 1)) + 1
    end.i <- c(start.i[-1] - 1, length(i))
    data.frame(from = i[start.i], to = i[end.i])
}
```

Comparing performance:

```
tt <- rep(t, 100)
library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(f = f(tt, 9), f2 = f2(tt, 9))
# Unit: microseconds
# expr     min       lq   median       uq      max neval
#    f 578.733 582.0575 584.7530 594.4130 1177.366   100
#   f2 350.153 354.1275 358.5175 378.0135 1186.022   100
```

Comment: Just out of interest, how does the performance look for `tt` of length, say, 1e5?

Comment: @CarlWitthoft It actually not only depends on the length of the vector but also the structure. I tried a few different ones and using `f2` was between 1.5 and 9 times faster.

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like

```
bool started = false;
int start = -1;
int end = -1;
for(i in t.length) :
    if(t[i]==wantedNumber) started = true ; start = i ;
    else if (started && t[i]!=wantedNumber) end = i ; break;
```

Comment: could you show how to determine which number it searches for?

Comment: put the code in a function and pass it as arg. you could return the indexes like [start, end]. the code is pseudo so it is not r code.

Comment: i understand now...just because I would like to do this for all numbers in the vector (so the result of unique(t) is there a bit of a quicker way to do it then to rerun the loop again and again?